# При создании в массив, попадают элементы из предыдущего

Tags: c, массивы, строки

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{

    char arr[] = {'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 't'};
    char arr2[] = {'w', 'h', 'a', 't'};

    printf("%s\n", arr);  // Выводит 'is it'
    printf("%s\n", arr2); // Выводит 'whatis it

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Я недавно изучаю си, и не совсем понимаю почему так получается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что при выводе через `%s` символы выводятся поочередно, пока не встретится нулевой символ - признак конца строки.

У вас же такого символа в массивах не предусмотрено. Чтобы это были именно две *строки*, можно сделать так:

```
char arr[] = {'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 't', '\0'};
char arr2[] = {'w', 'h', 'a', 't', '\0'};
```

или так:

```
char arr[] = "is it";
char arr2[] = "what";
```

(Обратите внимание на двойные кавычки - в этом случае нулевой символ будет добавлен автоматически.)

Ну, а выводит оба массива - просто они оказались рядом в памяти...